# How to nominate a post for Help & Improvement when it just needs a little help & improvement?

Tags: support, flags, help-improvement

Suppose I read a post, and I think that it could be improved by some obvious edits. But I don't have time to do the edits right now. So I think to myself "Hey, I'll get the post into the help & improvement queue, and somebody else can fix it!"

It looks like the way to do that is to flag the post as VLQ, which [sends it to triage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png). But the actual verbiage for VLQ says:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

The post isn't that bad, it just needs a little edit! And on a more practical note, I'm afraid some mod might suspend my account for abusing the VLQ flag.

Is there another way to handle this situation?

Comment: If you don't have the time to do the edits right now you could always follow it or favorite it and then come back and do them later.

Comment: @RobertLongson That probably wouldn't work. I'd look at my favorite list six months later and wonder what that post is doing in there.

Comment: If you don't then have the urge to edit, it must not have been necessary. Win-win.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that now (unless you are looking at posts in the "Triage" queue which directly sends posts to the H&I queue on the famous "Requires Editing" action).  So either spend extra minute to edit the post or just let it be. If you really feel the need to change the post - write a comment explaining the suggested edit or follow/favorite the question and remember to come back soon.

VLQ/NAA flags are absolutely not suitable for "post ... just needs a little edit!" case. Losing the flagging privilege for abusing such flags would be perfectly fair.

---

Treating this post as a feature-request:

I don't see how doing what you want properly - by writing a detailed explanation of what you want to change in the post - would be any faster than doing it yourself. As you pointed out in "I'd look at my favorite list six months later and wonder what that post is doing in there" comment just a flag "deserves an edit" is unlikely to be use useful.

I think its better to do nothing in such case rather than trying to create some sort of process to nominate posts for edit. If question is really useful someone else will likely find time to make that change on they own, but if question is not going to be visited often than extra effort that you (and potentially several other people if your suggestion is implemented) would just waste time that could be spent on more pressing needs for the site.